# Android: how to store user location and later display route traversed by user in serverside web application

Tags: java, android, kml

I am developing a product for tracking user location.

This consists of two parts:

1. Android application developed in Java : This application needs to track and store the route taken by the user and upload it to server. I am using firebase and firestore for the persistence.
2. Server side web application developed using Angular JS : Admin user uses this application to view the route traversed by the application user. This application is hosted in firebase.

I have given thoughts on using KML to store entire route taken by the user and then upload it to server. But I don't know whether this is the right solution as there is very less support for the KML.

Problems are :

1. KML out of the box support in android
2. How often to save the co-ordinates
3. Size of the KML file

Please let me know if there is any other alternative for this.

Answer (score 0):

I would explore storing the coordinate information alongside timestamps in firebase, then writing server side code to dynamically create a KML document with those timestamps when a user wants to view a route in the web. How often to save coordinates would probably come down to something like the speed the user is moving and/or relative distance between current location and location of last save...you might also want to track if a user remains in a certain place for an extended period of time, so you should probably have a max time limit between saves for when a user isn't moving.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. Earlier I thought about storing the coordinates by pushing it in to firestore. But I want to avoid too frequent pushes to firestore, that is why I started to think about creating a KML in Android app itself and then upload it to firestore. Any thoughts about this? Or am I missing anything here?

Comment: If the admin user doesn't need to see the route the user takes in real-time, why don't you just save the coordinate data locally and make a push whenever you want. Don't really see why you have create the KML on the client side if you think the file would be too big.